# What is the most efficient way to set a lot of notifications?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am creating a calendar app where you can set unlimited amount of activities which trigger alarmManager at start. And I am not sure what would be the best way to set the alarms.

Lets say we have 50.000 alarms which starting times are loaded from the database and save in array in MainActivity and we need to set them. We also have the method for setting a notification in MainActivity.

The way I wanted to do it was to set first (closest) alarm and in the broadcastReceiver I would set the next following alarm. But this idea didn't work because I have the list and method is in mainActivity and so I needed to get the instance of that mainActivity. The context I get in the onReceive method returns different context, so it can't be accessed through that. I also looked for a way to pass activity instance in an intent but found nothing. Lastly I tried to create interface in the broadcastReceiver class and pass the instance somehow this way but it was a dead end as well.

The other option that came to my mind was to set the first X alarms on start in the main thread and then the rest in separate thread but that doesn't seem much efficient.

So is it possible to somehow get the context of mainActivity in BroadcastReceiver? If not what's the most efficient way to set a lot of notifications?

Appreciate all the help

Comment: "So is it possible to somehow get the context of mainActivity in BroadcastReceiver?" -- no. The activity might not exist at the time the alarm is triggered. "If not what's the most efficient way to set a lot of notifications?" -- use the basic strategy that you are doing (set an alarm for the first one). When that alarm is triggered, in addition to raising the notification, start a `WorkManager` bit of work to query your database for the next event and schedule the next alarm.

Comment: Also what do you mean you have it in the MainActivity?? This type of info is stored in room databases, which are accessible through the broadcast receiver. I'd recommend creating a repository though, to keep things clean and consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time flew by and as @CommonsWare and @Richard Onslow Roper suggested I was able to come up with a correct solution.

As suggested I created new repository where to store the notifications. When the first notification is triggered, meaning we're in BroadcastReceiver.class onReceive method, it will set the notification and then queue the next by scheduling new work in workManager.